# Lower semi-continuity of the convolution of two nonnegative functions

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, lp-spaces, convolution

A function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ is lower semi-continuous if $(x_n)_n\to x\Rightarrow \liminf\limits_n\phi(x_n)\geqslant \phi(x)$ or (equivalent) $\forall a\in\mathbb{R},\{\phi\leqslant a\}$ is closed.

Show that the convolution of two nonnegative measurable functions is upper semi-continuous.
Any hints ? Thanks !

**My work:**

I wrote
$$\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}f(x_n-y)g(y)dy$$
but only having nonnegativeness does not tell me anything on this integral, especially how this sequence would converge...

Comment: Do you know Fatou's lemma?

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets We have $\liminf\limits_n f_n\star g\geqslant \int \liminf\limits_n f(x_n-y)g(y)dy$ by Fatou's lemma. Then we need to show that $f(x_n-y)g(y)\to f(x-y)g(y)$ when $x_n\to x$. Can this be done by dominated convergence ?